# MailMessage won't send to more than 2 recipients?

Tags: asp.net, mailmessage

In ASP.NET I am sending a MailMessage but it won't go through. The code I am using is

```
message.To.Add(email1 + ", " + email2 + ", " + email3);
```

When I do this I never receive my mail. However if I use this code:

```
message.To.Add(email1 + ", " + email2);
```

It sends just fine every time. Anybody know what is going on here? All 3 emails are the same (for testing purposes) and have been verified to be correct while debugging. I tried inserting a different email address for the third and still nothing went through. I may be missing something obvious...

EDIT:
Everyone is telling me to add them individually which may well be good advice if everyone agrees upon it. The reason I didn't do this previously and I just tried it again with three *seperate* addresses and none of them were sent. Maybe I have another issue entirely if that is supposed to work?

EDIT: For anyone with the same problem in the future here is what I did. When creating the MailMessage I didn't create it with any parameters and instead specified the From parameter seperately. I wrapped the From and all To emails in `new MailAddress()` and the combination of all those changes appeared to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `To` property of MailMessage is a collection, so you should call 
`message.To.Add` 3 times if want to send to 3 email addresses.

Comment: I was under the impression if you were adding more than 1 address it you were supposed to use a comma delimited list, rather than call Add multiple times?

Comment: If you were using the version of MailMessage in .NET 1.1 or earlier, this may have been the case. Since .NET 2.0, the To field is a collection.

Comment: I see I'm using 3.5...good to know thanks. I think I have some other issue since the proper way of adding them doesn't work for me at all.

Answer (score 4):

Just call `Add` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of contencating mail addressed into a single Add statement, you should be adding them one at a time:

```
message.To.Add(email1);
message.To.Add(email2);
message.To.Add(email3);
```

Since you're adding to a collection.

Also, if the addresses are the same, the function usually doesn't add it twice in my experience.  This may be a behavior of the Mailmessage.To.Add function, or it could be that when it gets to me Outlook has stripped out duplicates, but it *looks* to me like it filters out duplicates.  You may be seeing the same on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
message.to.add(email1);
message.to.add(email2);
message.to.add(email3);
message.to.add(email4);
```

Hope this helps

Harvey Sather

Answer (score 0):

I store message recipients in the web.config file and then handle it like this

```
 string lstrDistributitionList = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP_DISTRIBUTION_LIST"];
                    string[] lastrDistributitionList = lstrDistributitionList.Split(';');

                    for (Int32 loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < lastrDistributitionList.Length; loopCounter++)
                    {
                        msg.To.Add(lastrDistributitionList[loopCounter]);
                    }
```

Harvey Sather